# What is the default nursery size for JRockit R27.6.0_1.6.0_05 when -XgcPrio:pausetime is used?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, jrockit

JRockit [R28 documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1011858) says that the default value of nursery size (`-Xns`) is "10 MB per logical processor" when `-Xgc:pausetime` flag is used. [Elsewhere](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E15289_01/doc.40/e15062/optionx.htm#i1021675) in the same document, they say that `-XgcPrio` is now deprecated in favor of `-Xgc`, which from the look of things, is the same configuration.

JRockit [R27 documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html#wp999534) says that the default value of nursery size (`-Xns`) is "50% of free heap" when `-Xgcprio:pausetime` flag is used.

I have a customer using R27.6.0_1.6.0_05. I tested on R27.5.0-110_o-99226-1.6.0_03-20080528-1505-linux-ia32, R27.6.5-32_o-121899-1.6.0_14-20091001-2113-linux-ia32 and R28.1.0-123-138454-1.6.0_20-20101014-1350-linux-ia32 - the default nursery size seems to 10MB when `-XgcPrio:pausetime` is used. Unfortunately, I cannot find binary for the exact JRockit version from Oracle website. So, does anyone know what the default version nursery size is on R27.6.0_1.6.0_05?

I am not familiar with JRockit, but I am surprised that a parameter such as this had a huge change in default value between two releases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for -Xns in R27 is wrong. Default values for -Xns are (both in R27 and R28):

> `-Xgcprio:pausetime`: 10 MB per logical processor
>    `-Xgcprio:throughput`: 50% of free heap

Note, however, that when using -XgcPrio the JVM can switch between having a nursery and not having a nursery. The default values apply when a nursery exists.

> "Elsewhere in the same document, they say that -XgcPrio is now deprecated in favor of -Xgc, which from the look of things, is the same configuration."

Yes, in R28 `-Xgc:pausetime` is the same thing as `-XgcPrio:pausetime`.

Comment: Did an older JRockit version have the default for -Xns as half of free heap when -Xgcprio:pausetime was used? Or was it always 10MB/processor and was incorrectly documented? I am trying to determine if the meaning of the flag switched on my customer when they upgraded to a newer version.

Comment: I believe it was always 10MB/processor.